# 3 level Neo4j query ! So slow, 39 seconds execution time

Tags: neo4j

Please check out the image of the graph I'm trying to match below. I dont think I'm doing anything that complex, so I'm not sure why Neo4j is so slow.

I have 20MB of data in my database (~300 nodes and 350 relationships). I've indexed each node and property. My query is taking 39 seconds to run EVERYTIME I run it. I get the results that I want, but the query is painfully slow

I've tried combining movie1 and movie2 to hang off the same  All_Movies, but the query was still slow

```
 MATCH
( mainGuy:Person { uri:'http://example.com/foo' })<-[:IN]-(movie1:Movie) ,

(movie1)<-[:TYPE|:SUBTYPE*1..3]-(allM:All_Movies  ),

( nonMoF:Person)<-[:IN]-(movie1),

(movie2:Movie)<-[:TYPE|:SUBTYPE*1..3]-(allM2:All_Movies  ),

( pou:Person)<-[:IN]-(movie2),

(pou2:Person)<-[:IN]-(movie2),

( reqGuy:Person)<-[:ACTED_IN]-( movie2),

( nonMoF)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(movie2) ,

(reqGuy)<-[:NAME*0..3]-(cnBlah:OtherData)  ,

(oin656:IdInfo)<-[r:OTHER*0..3]-(reqGuy) 

WHERE  allM2.name  = 'Lionheart'  AND  allM.name  = 'Lionheart'  AND not(  ()-[:NAME]->(oin656)  )

RETURN reqGuy, cnBlah , oin656, movie1
```

[image: Neo4j graph in my Database]

Comment: It looks like you put an RDF model into a property graph.

Comment: You span up a huge number of potential paths.

Comment: Some of the information you match you never use.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should perform better, as it reduces the cardinality in between. But your model is still questionable from a property-graph perspective.

if you can share your example db we can also help you better

```
create index on :Person(uri);
create index on :All_Movies(name);



MATCH (mainGuy:Person { uri:'http://example.com/foo' })<-[:IN]-(movie1:Movie)<-[:TYPE|:SUBTYPE*1..3]-(allM:All_Movies)
WHERE allM.name  = 'Lionheart' 
WITH distinct movie1

MATCH ( nonMoF:Person)<-[:IN]-(movie1),( nonMoF)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(movie2)

MATCH (movie2:Movie)<-[:TYPE|:SUBTYPE*1..3]-(allM2:All_Movies  )

WHERE allM2.name  = 'Lionheart'

WITH movie2, collect(movie1) as movies

MATCH ( reqGuy:Person)<-[:ACTED_IN]-( movie2)
MATCH (reqGuy)<-[:NAME*0..3]-(cnBlah:OtherData) 
WITH reqGuy, collect(distinct cnBlah) as cnBlahs, movies

MATCH (oin656:IdInfo)<-[r:OTHER*0..3]-(reqGuy) WHERE not(()-[:NAME]->(oin656))

RETURN reqGuy, cnBlahs , collect(distinct oin656) as oins, movies;
```

Comment: So you're saying Neo4j cant handle that query in less then 39 seconds  because of the model I'm using ? There's only ~300 nodes in the database. Come on !